# React input defaultValue doesn't update with props changes

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router

I have created an app using React, Redux & React Router. When the URL changes, the value of the query parameter `personId` should be used to get the correct person object from an array:

```
mapStateToProps = (state, router) => ({
    onePerson: state.persons.filter((person, i) => person.id === router.params.personId)[0]
})
```

I also have an input element that depends on that person's name:

```
<input type="text" defaultValue={this.props.onePerson.name} />
```

As the URL changes, and the `props` updates accordingly, the input element's `defaultValue` doesn't change. How can I overcome this issue? Note that I don't want to use "controlled input".

Comment: You should do this filter logic in the component where you are setting that default value, not the `mapStateToProps`

Comment: `mapStateToProps` is in the component which contains input with `defaultValue` . if i'm not going to set props `mapStateToProps`  where else can i access application state to set props?

Comment: It's not actually *in* the component, it's in the container. You want your component to read it and do the filter. If it is something you only want done once upon load you can take advantage of the react component lifecycle functions like componentDidMount.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the `defaultValue` is only used **the first time** the component gets rendered. If you need to update the value later, you have to use a controlled input.

**Update:**

From the [React Docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html):

> The defaultValue and defaultChecked props are only used during initial
>   render. If you need to update the value in a subsequent render, you
>   will need to use a controlled component.

I guess you **could** remove and re-add the component to give it a new `defaultValue`, **but you really shouldn't**.

Comment: is there any way to force re-render in response to router change?

Comment: Yes you can force a re-render, but that won't help you here. The defaultValue is only used during the **first** render. Why don't you want to use a controlled input?

Comment: because i have a person array in my store , which user got from server  
and user can change each one in a form ... then press save to change person in server
but in controlled input , for changing input i have to change the person in stroe by action in onChange of input
so if user changes input and NOT press save .. the store shows change in person thats not actually saved

Comment: In that case you could store both the name from the server, and the edited name. So if the input is untouched, you show the actual name. Then once, it's changed, you add that change to the editedName and show that in the input instead. Now you can easily submit that new name, or revert back to the old.

Comment: seems very nice . tnx my friend

Answer (score 0):

I find easy to destroy an element, clean all data and replace it with the new one with :

```
ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(document.querySelector("#myParentElement"));

        if(document.querySelector("#myParentElement")){
            ReactDOM.render(
                <MyComponent name={name}  />,
                document.querySelector("#myParentElement")
            );
        };
```

You can use also this version of unmount method:

```
ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this).parentNode);
```